# How to manipulate a text paragraph line by line in python (of type unicode)?

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I have a variable (of type unicode) that has some text in it. This text I take from another variable which is of type class 'bs4.element.Tag'(beautiful soup).

Example of text in this variable is:

1234 words words

1234 words1 words2

What I'm trying to do is manipulate this text line by line, so I trim every line in two parts: one to contain the first four characters i.e 1234, and the other part with the text only.

Regards

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: @FallenAngel I had put it was inside <> and stackoverflow removed it.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry why dont you just give me www.google.com. I tried first googling but I couldn't find anything, that's why I'm asking a question. Jeez, what a community we are.

Comment: did read the official documentation? about types? slicing ?

Comment: Yes but I cannot figure out how to manipulate line by line. I know about strip functions.

Comment: You mean about slice()?

Comment: From all these comments, what I understand is you do not know hat you are doing, and this is not good in programming. I mean, you are working with a beautiful Soup `class method` or ` class attribute` and probably you can not slice or split a `class instance` or an `attribute of a class` unless attribute is string based or retuns something that is string based

Comment: The Beautifulsoup element I assigned to a new variable that when I type() it shows, its unicode. Is there any way to manipulate it line by line?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module?

Comment: Then, your variable stores a string object (unicode or not, it is not important in your situation i geuess). Yuou can print it to see line-breakers. I mean, your string must be split into lines without using `\r` or `\n` (otherwise splitlines would work). There might be some `html` element that causes the line-break (I am not sure) then youcan use basic index based slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for method like 'split()' or 'splitline()' (depending on your variable).

This will be something like :

```
    var.split() # if you want to split using the space
    # or
    var[:4] # if you are sure that you need the first 4 characters.
```

Comment: I've already tried these ways but didnt work because my variable contains multilines and I want to trim for every line. I tried also splitline() but shows attribute error: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'splitline'